# Is it possible to create custom statements or language extensions in C#?

Tags: c#

Is it possible, in C# to create custom statements?

I would like to be able to create a new loop statement like this:

```
ifWhile(cond1, cond2) {
    // code
}
```

Where if `cond1` is true, the loop loops while `cond2` is true.

I am trying to turn this tedious (and redundant) code:

```
if (rs.HasRows) {
    while (rs.Read()) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Into this more concise code:

```
ifWhile (rs.HasRows, rs.Read()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Why not just `while (rs.Read())`? If it doesn't have any rows, it won't read anything.

Comment: Yes and no. "Yes" insofar as you can fork Roslyn and extend the C# language however you like, but you cannot extend C# language syntax _like that_ (e.g. introducing new program-flow-control statements and syntax).

Comment: Even if there are hundreds of these in your code, this seems like a small win in the grand scheme of things.  If coding tedium is your issue, I'd use a code template instead (assuming you have a nice IDE like DevStudio).

Comment: Upvote to Llama.  Thanks, but I was just using that as a common example that everyone would recognise.  I have lots of potential uses for such a construct.  I thought it would be more clear if I used an example everyone would understand.  Thanks!

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace - Can you show us some of the other potential uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't get that exact syntax, but you could use `Func<T>` and `Action` params to get something similar:

```
public static void IfWhile(bool cond1, Func<bool> cond2, Action code)
{
    if (!cond1) return;
    while(cond2())
        code();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
IfWhile(rs.HasRows, () => rs.Read(), () =>
{
    // Do stuff.
});
```

Comment: Yes, or if Lamda funtions aren't your thing:while(ifwhile(cond1, cond2) {code;}

Comment: What, @FrankMerrow?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create new language features directly in C#, but you can create methods and/or extension methods that will get you closer.

Let's see how close we can get.

Here's what you're after:

```
ifWhile(cond1, cond2) {
    // do stuff
}
```

And you want that to have the same semantics as this:

```
if (rs.HasRows) {
    while (rs.Read()) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

What's important here is that `rs.Read()` gets called during each iteration of the `while` loop, so you need to use a `Func<bool>` rather than a `bool` for this second parameter.

You also can't just write a block of code, you need to run an `Action`.

So, as 41686d6564 says, you can do this:

```
public static void IfWhile(bool cond1, Func<bool> cond2, Action code)
{
    if (!cond1) return;
    while(cond2())
        code();
}
```

And that allows you to write:

```
IfWhile(rs.HasRows, () => rs.Read(), () =>
{
    // Do stuff.
});
```

It's close to what you initially wanted, but it's not ideal. I think the mess there is as bad, or, if not, worse, as simply repeating your code.

Here's an alternative that might be worth considering.

Let's flesh out what the `rs` code might look like:

```
public interface IRS
{
    bool HasRows { get; }
    bool Read();
    IRow CurrentRow { get; }
}

public interface IRow { }
```

Now, that gives us a alternative way to remove duplication. Let's create an extension method to wrap all of this into a simple call.

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void IfHasRowsReadAll(this IRS rs, Action<IRow> action)
    {
        if (rs.HasRows)
        {
            while (rs.Read())
            {
                action(rs.CurrentRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can go ahead and write this code:

```
rs.IfHasRowsReadAll(r =>
{
    // do stuff
});
```

The `r` that is passed through to the `// do stuff` code is the instance of `IRow`.

This is one option for how to simplify this code.

Finally, there is a final extension method that might even be a better alternative. Try this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IRow> GetRowsOrEmpty(this IRS rs)
{
    if (rs.HasRows)
    {
        while (rs.Read())
        {
            yield return rs.CurrentRow;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can write this:

```
foreach (IRow r in rs.GetRowsOrEmpty())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

I think that most cleanly expresses your intent and now it can be easily used with the rest of the LINQ operators.

Answer (score -1):

I am referring to the code above which passes in a Action variable for the code you want to execute.  My personal preference would be more like this:

```
while (ifWhile(cond1, cond2) {
   code;
}
```

As a personal preference, I think Lamda functions are often overused.  They have their place, but only when it makes code easier to understand . . . not "just because you can".  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: "only when it makes code easier to understand" - that is a very subjective and limited way of looking at it.

Comment: "I am referring to the code above" - what code above?

Comment: And finally, what you're proposing doesn't have the same semantics that the OP is looking for. You might need to discuss that.